# Refactor several nested for loops with conditions

Tags: python, refactoring

Consider following piece of code

```
for a in generator1():
    if test(a):
        for b in generator2():
            if test(a, b):
                for c in generator3():
                    if test(a, b, c):
                        print "Found {} {} {}".format(a, b, c)
```

Using `test` before each loop is essential since generators can yield a lot of values (10^6-10^8). I do not want to do expensive computations when it is clear that due to value of `a` or `b` entire triple won't pass test.

Can this code be simplified? What if I want to add more inner loops (test fours of fives)?

Comment: use lists. Example: `generators = [generator1, generator2]`; and call test with list too: `args = [a] test(args) ... args += [b] test(args)`

Comment: @nikniknik2016 Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'd probably write this as recursive generators instead

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I can upgrade to Python 3.x if it will allow to make code significantly easier

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `itertools` and `all` with slicing:

```
ag = range(10)
bg = range(10)
cg = range(10)

import itertools

# only returns true if all numbers are equal
def test(args):
    return len(set(args)) <= 1

for comb in itertools.product(ag, bg, cg):
    if all(test(comb[:limit]) for limit in range(len(comb) + 1)):
        print "found", comb
```

- `itertools` generates all combinations of the generators.
- `all` is used instead of your `if`s.
- Finally, I use slicing to generate all arguments (prefixes of the list).